# What are some appropriate responses to the speaker who told you that her birthday was yesterday

Tags: responses

I would like to thank you userr2684291 and  FumbleFingers for their help on my previous post (I have deleted it because I don't want them to get into any trouble).

(I was doing some English learning test at home.)
The previous question is this:

> Speaker: My birthday's yesterday. (She meant her birthday was yesterday)
>   (thank you FumbleFingers for pointing out the mistake)
>
> (Choose your response to the speaker)
>
> A: I was at home yesterday.
>
> B: Oh, how old will you be?
>
> C: Oh, congratulations!

Because B is wrong (answered by userr2684291), and A is not correct,
C is the only best choice out of the three.

My question is, isn't it weird to say this to someone's previous or upcoming birthday?

> Oh, congratulations!

The one I heard most is this

> Happy birthday to you!

But I am not very sure if **Oh, congratulations!** and  **Happy birthday to you!** can be used to respond to someone whose birthday was yesterday.

What are some appropriate responses to the speaker in this situation?

Comment: You can choose to omit "to you".

Comment: Or you can just frown and say, "Oh. I didn't get you anything."

Comment: Congratulations is a little bit weird, except for perhaps a milestone birthday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you'd either apologize for forgetting it or express surprise because you didn't know. Then you could say:

> Belated *Happy Birthday*!

People also say:

> Happy belated birthday!

Comment: I am wondering is it OK to say: my "long overdue" happy birthday!

Comment: @Cardinal Yes, you could say that, but it's rather unextraordinary. The shorter the better, the more effective.

Comment: I see, but what does "unextraordinary" mean?